# open.db is not found in opennebula3.4.1

Tags: opennebula

open.db is missing in the home location of oneadmin i.e. /var/. Because of this whenever I start open nebula Database mismatch occurs, what could be done ? any suggestions?

-Linda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenNebula sqlite DB (OpenNebula default DB) is called `one.db`, and it is placed in `/var/lib/one`. Database version mismatch errors arise when an update is performed to OpenNebula and 'oned' is started before the DB is migrated.

The straight solution would be to run `onedb upgrade -s /var/lib/one/one.db` and start OpenNebula. The radical solution (that entails losing all the information about hosts, VMs, vnets, etc) would be to erase the DB and start OpenNebula.